# Select all records between 2 hours of different day

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to create a lottery system, and for that I need to get all tickets generated. But I need to check if ticket was previously generate for an user and for that I need to select record between 12:00 ( noon ) and next 12:00 ( noon )

But if I am the next day, at 11:00 AM, what is the request to do ?

If user check if ticket is created after noon, what is the request ?

I have try this but I think it's not the right way :

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$current_hour = date("H");
if($current_hour>=12)
{
    //Noon is done, we select ticket
    $stmt = $databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM loto WHERE user_name=:username AND date_game > :current_date ");
    $stmt->bindParam(":current_date",$current_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);   $stmt->bindParam(":username",$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
else
{
    //Before noon, we select ticket
}
```

Comment: Look up the use of the functions NOW(),  INTERVAL and BETWEEN. You can 'do math' with dates and times. It's easy.

Comment: Can you explain your idea ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure in lotteries two people can have the same ticket and the prize is shared, do you mean a raffle?

Comment: I just want check if a ticket generated by an user is done between 12:00 and 12:00 . Curently I use this : $stmt = `$databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM loto WHERE user_name=:username AND date_game BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND NOW()");` but it's not good